# Computing BMI and How to Prevent Rounding Up Floating Points (Java)

Tags: java, rounding

I'm writing a program that will calculate the BMI of a person. Here's the assignment that I was given:

"Body Mass Index (BMI) is a measure of health on weight. It can be calculated by taking your weight in kilograms and dividing by the square of your height in meters. Write a program that prompts the user to enter a weight W in pounds and height H in inches and displays the BMI. Note that one pound is 0.45359237 kilograms and one inch is 0.0254 meters."

Input: (Line 1) Real number within 50 to 200
       (Line 2) Real number within 10 to 100

Output: BMI value (Floating point should only be printed until the second decimal point)

The problem is that whenever I use "System.out.printf("%.2f\n", BMI)", the output is rounded up rather than cutting off the rest of the decimal point. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double weight = input.nextDouble();
        double height = input.nextDouble();

        double weightKG;
        double heightM;
        double heightMSquare;
        double BMI;

        final double kilogram = 0.45359237;
        final double meter = 0.0254;

        while ((weight > 200) || (weight < 50)) // Error catching code.
        {
            weight = input.nextDouble();
        }
        while ((height > 100) || (height < 10))
        {
            height = input.nextDouble();
        }

        weightKG = weight * kilogram; // Convert pounds and inches to 
kilograms and meters.
        heightM = height * meter;

        heightMSquare = Math.pow(heightM, 2); // Compute square of height in 
meters.

        BMI = weightKG / heightMSquare; // Calculate BMI by dividing weight 
by height.

        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", BMI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method I wrote that solves this with regexes and string manipulation.

```
private static String format2Dp(double x) {
    String d = Double.toString(x);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\.(\\d+)").matcher(d);
    if (!m.find()) {
        return d;
    }
    String decimalPart = m.group(1);
    if (decimalPart.length() == 1) {
        return d.replaceAll("\\.(\\d+)", "." + decimalPart + "0");
    }
    return d.replaceAll("\\.(\\d+)", "." + decimalPart.substring(0, 2));
}
```

What I did was turning the double to a string, extract the decimal part out of it and substringing the decimal part. If the decimal part is only 1 character long, add a zero to the end.

This method works with numbers expressed in scientific notation as well.